# Pygame image, get the current image file loaded

Tags: oop, python-3.x, pygame

I am using the pygame.image.load to load a picture to the game surface:

```
self.picture = pygame.image.load("some_img.png")
```

While the game is running, this image file can be change (with some events), like by pressing the button y the picture in the self.picture is changed into other image file.
What I really need, is to get the current image file name loaded into the self.picture each time.

I try to print the self.picture to see what the value is but, is not a kind of picture file name but, object code:

```
<Surface(30x52x30 SW)>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load), it returns a [`pygame.Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. As far as can be seen from the documentation, there is no way to find the filename of the original image back from the `Surface`. I would suggest using another variable to hold this name:

```
self.picname = "some_img.png"
self.picture = pygame.image.load(self.picname)
```

Comment: I use this method but I need to make the program more memory-friendly, and this is the reason why I ask for filename return from pygame.image.load. But if there is no way excpect of holding the name in a variable, nevermind. Cheers.